# TensorflowLite output tensorsor data extraction

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

guys I'm working on a object detection project, using a tflite model in Android Studio. I've trained the yolo v8 model and then converted it to tflite. Now the Issue I am facing is I am not able to extract location coordinates, class, confidence score  from the "output" varibale?[code generated after I imported the model in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8D19.png)
[description of output tensor from neutron.app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qUYc.png)

I tried finding the solution on chat gpt and other ai chat bots , tried reading the documentation , checked up on youtube for solutions .

Comment: please this the attached image for understanding